# Zend Framework: Ajax post data

Tags: ajax, json, zend-framework

That is my function:

```
function deleteAutoAd(id, title) {
    alert(title);                                                                         
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/deleteautoad',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id : id,
            title : title
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

In this function when I try alert(title) and popup 'This is title'(because title = 'This is title'). But in ajax/deleteautoad I try this:

```
public function deleteautoadAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        echo $param1 = $this->_request->getParam('id');
        echo $param2 = $this->_request->getParam('title');
    }
}
```

Echo param1 show 5, but echo param2 don't show nothing.

Comment: check var_dump($_POST) to see what is posted. Also check in your browser what data is posted.

Comment: I try var_dump($_POST), but don't do nothing I don't know why, with HttpFox I found this post and postdata is: id=4&&title=This is title

Comment: I have tested your code and deleteautoadAction echoes id and title.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should try :

```
function deleteAutoAd(id, title) {
    alert(title);                                                                         
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/deleteautoad',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'id' : id, // Note the quotes
            'title' : title // Note the quotes
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

regards

mimiz

Comment: Before I post my question I try this and don't have results

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer

Also, For my application, I also have to post the full url. So you might want to try

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
```

and then on your url

```
url: root+'/ajax/deleteautoad',
```

Comment: Although, in hindsight, my application is 'widgetised' so these things can be called from anywhere ... which probably explains why I use static urls. (it's been a while since I worked on that area)

Comment: I try this and that from previos previous post but don't have result only echo id, but title don't.

Answer (score 1):

You should return from controller a valid JSON with `Success` status.

```
public function deleteautoadAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $x->Status = 'Success';
        $x->Message = $this->_getParam('id') . $this->_getParam('title');
        $this->_helper->json($x);
    }
}
```

And also you should change your `alert` statement

```
function deleteAutoAd(id, title) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/deleteautoad',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id : id,
            title : title
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now alert id and title, but I need to use title value in my action. How to get title I try $this->_request->getParam('title'); but don't have result

Answer (score 0):

Moved from the OP question to a CW answer:

> I fixed the problem by removing: `dataType: 'json'`.